# Please help identify this mech robot set

Tags: set-identification

This is some kind of mech robot. I guess it is coming from some Japanese story as on its left leg it has some Japanese writing.

I would love to rebuild/complete it but can't figure out what it is.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's part of [Thunder Raider (70723)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70723-1), a Ninjago set from 2014 :

[image]